# Setting thread context class loader in java application

Tags: java

This is my scenario,
I have a command-line application, where I load components at runtime using a URL class loader.

Everything was working fine till a fried deployed an component based on a library called rest-assured.

In the deployment scenario all the jars including rest-assured, gson and jackson are loaded in the URL classloader.

However when I create the URL classloader and load the components, I am not changing the Thread's context class loader.

The rest-assured code is relying on the context class loader to check if gson or Jackson is in the classpath.

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.jayway.restassured/rest-assured-common/2.3.2/com/jayway/restassured/mapper/resolver/ObjectMapperResolver.java

I have two questions

1. I am not setting any context class loaders, is it the right thing to do?
2. Is the rest-assured library correct in assuming that the gson/Jackson classes will be available only in the context class loader?

Comment: I'm the creator of REST Assured and I'd like to know the answer for this as well. Would be happy to change the code if needed.

Comment: I was hoping for a answer/guidance on this forum. Can you modify the code to first look for the classes in the classloader that loads ObjectMapperResolver and uses context classloader only if it classes are not found.

Comment: I've added your suggestion and committed a new snapshot. Try it out by depending on version 2.3.4-SNAPSHOT after having added the following repo:

<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <snapshots />
        </repository>
</repositories>